# why image is not display as same as inserted in drawable folder?

Tags: java, android

I apply two images **"+" and "--"** for  collapse and expand in my expandablelist view .My problem is that when i expand image display **"|"** it should display like that "--"
why it rotate ?here is my code

```
 <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/lvExp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                android:groupIndicator="@drawable/test"
                />
```

**Selector**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/positive" android:state_empty="true">  </item>            
           <item android:drawable="@drawable/minus" android:state_expanded="true"></item>                
           <item android:drawable="@drawable/positive"></item>


</selector>
```

is there any other way to show image on collapsible row and expand row ..Here is my whole code ..

**Main Activity**

```
package info.androidhive.expandablelistview;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        // Listview Group click listener
        expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, long id) {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Listview Group expanded listener
        expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                if(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) != null)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // Listview Group collasped listener
        expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        // Listview on child click listener
        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                                + " : "
                                + listDataChild.get(
                                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                        childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    /*
     * Preparing the list data
     */
    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Top 250");
        listDataHeader.add("Now Showing");
        listDataHeader.add("Coming Soon..");

        // Adding child data
        List<String> top250 = new ArrayList<String>();
        top250.add("The Shawshank Redemption");
        top250.add("The Godfather");
        top250.add("The Godfather: Part II");
        top250.add("Pulp Fiction");
        top250.add("The Good, the Bad and the Ugly");
        top250.add("The Dark Knight");
        top250.add("12 Angry Men");

        List<String> nowShowing = new ArrayList<String>();
        nowShowing.add("The Conjuring");
        nowShowing.add("Despicable Me 2");
        nowShowing.add("Turbo");
        nowShowing.add("Grown Ups 2");
        nowShowing.add("Red 2");
        nowShowing.add("The Wolverine");

        /*List<String> comingSoon = new ArrayList<String>();
        comingSoon.add("2 Guns");
        comingSoon.add("The Smurfs 2");
        comingSoon.add("The Spectacular Now");
        comingSoon.add("The Canyons");
        comingSoon.add("Europa Report");*/

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), top250); // Header, Child data
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), nowShowing);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), null);
    }
}
```

**Adapter**

```
package info.androidhive.expandablelistview;


public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
            HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        if(this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))!=null)
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#f4f4f4" >

            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/lvExp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                android:groupIndicator="@drawable/test"
                />   

</LinearLayout>
```

**group.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp" 
    android:background="#000000">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textColor="#f9f93d" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Selector**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_4" android:state_empty="true">  </item>            
               <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_3" android:state_expanded="true"></item>                
               <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_3"></item>
</selector>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image][image]

could you please tell me another way to achieve this functionality or could you please tell me where I am going wrong ?

Comment: Your image is only stretched vertically. Just make a better image with a big enough height that does not need to be stretched.

Comment: Actually I take my image horizontally ..why it show vertically

Comment: why it is streaching ?

Comment: `streaching` ? It is stretching because it is not high enough i think. The minus bar does not show vertically. It is still horizontally. The bar is only made higher: stretched. Make better images is the solution. The plus/positive image is stretched vertically too as everyone can see.

Comment: I think your solution is correct ...But I have one problem ..My third row don't have child ..Why it display (+) sign It should only display when There is child node of parent

Comment: I think that you should provide a different icon in your Selector .xml for state_empty `<item android:drawable="@drawable/positive" android:state_empty="true">`.

Comment: I already take different Icon ..could you please give email Id ?? ..so that I will send my code >actually my problem is that third parent don't have child but it show + sign  on row why

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63920/discussion-between-neetu-sharma-and-greenapps).

Comment: any update sir ..please tell why I See + sign

Comment: It seems that a three-state icon is not possible with a selector .xml file. You are not the first one who wants a different icon when the group has no childs. The solution is to disable the group indicator and making your own with an ImageView is proposed here: http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.nl/2011/06/hiding-group-indicator-for-empty-groups.html